# What is the best way to convert OOP classes to FP functions?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, functional-programming

I have found a GitHub repository full of JavaScript algorithms and data types. The thing is, everything is written in OOP. I myself, prefer a more FP approach using small, reusable functions. What are some best practices to convert classes to smaller consumable functions?

For now, I can come up with the following working example. Is this the way to go?

OOP:

```
class LinkedListNode {
  constructor(value, next = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }

  toString(callback) {
    return callback ? callback(this.value) : `${this.value}`;
  }
}
```

FP:

```
function toString(value, callback) {
  return callback ? callback(value) : `${value}`;
}

function Node(value, next = null) {
  return {
    value,
    next,
    toString(callback) {
      return toString(value, callback);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the distinction between functional and object-oriented programming. While I definitely prefer the second version of your code to the first, that is due to its superior encapsulation. Simply changing from a constructor to a factory doesn't change make something functional

Comment: Well, my entire code base is written in a functional way. I do not want to add a single class in order to implement a new data type, it seems a bit out of place? Also, this allows me to use `toString` wherever I want without it being dependent on the data structure.

Comment: @VeraPerrone I agree that the "functional" style tends to yield more reusable (and importantly testable code), but changing from a class to a doesn't get you that. However, this doesn't apply to your example, because you could easily use your freestanding `toString` to implement the `class`'s method, just as you did to implement the object literal's method.

Comment: @VeraPerrone While this is not a comprehensive definition, FP is primarily about leveraging higher order programming abstractions, transforming immutable values, and avoiding inheritance based approaches. In JavaScript, classes themselves can be higher order however.

Comment: If you prefer the functional paradigm without knowing how to code in it, then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why does every resource on FP suggest to never use classes then? Just wondering.

Comment: I doubt that you will have much fun with such an endeavor. Switching from OOP to FP is not just about extracting some functions and data types from classes but a completely different way of tackling problems. You would have to rewrite the entire repo and would wind up with something completely new.

Comment: This isn't a bad question per se, but way too broad for stackoverflow. Short answer with no justifications: The golden rule of FP is to separate the logic from code that performs side effects (like DOM access). Logic should be pure: any transform on data should return a new value rather than modifying the original. You can do all of that with classes (google functional programming in Java), but it's awkward and adds a lot of unnecessary boilerplate in JS. Explaining *why* all those points are valuable would take a book, but you can start [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM).

Comment: You can always write a `function toString(node) { return node.toString(); }` wrapper, as long as the `Node` is written functionally-minded (with immutable objects and no side effects), you can even use `class` syntax just fine for that.

Answer (score 3):

In your second example you still have a method attached to each instance, which is not ideal as soon as you want to reuse this method on a compatible interface. Also it does not play well with many FP js libraries.

To make it clear from the outside that it is not a constructor function, make it start lower case and add a prefix like create for example.

Make functions as pure as possible and do not mix code composition logic (compose, curry) with the business logic. (I talk about callback having nothing to do inside toString)

I am adding export to clearly show that at least 2 functions need to be exported.

```
export { nodeToString, createNode };

function nodeToString(node) {
  return `${node.value}`;
}

function createNode(value, next = null) {
  return {
    value,
    next
  };
}
```

It would be used like this

```
import { nodeToString, createNode } from "./x.js";

const node = createNode(`myvalue`);
const string = nodeToString(node);
```